# android app cannot find the class

Tags: android

I just begin to learn android. So I download a sample project from android website called "AdapterTransition". but I used ADT eclipse to complier and run app. I get the following error message

```
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894): Process: com.example.android.adaptertransition, PID: 894
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.adaptertransition/com.example.android.adaptertransition.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.adaptertransition.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.adaptertransition-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.adaptertransition-2, /system/lib]]
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.adaptertransition.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.adaptertransition-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.adaptertransition-2, /system/lib]]
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
04-06 13:54:18.010: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  ... 11 more
```

XML

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.adaptertransition"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android.adaptertransition.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ACTIVITY

```
package com.example.android.adaptertransition;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ViewAnimator;

import com.example.android.common.activities.SampleActivityBase;
import com.example.android.common.logger.Log;
import com.example.android.common.logger.LogFragment;
import com.example.android.common.logger.LogWrapper;
import com.example.android.common.logger.MessageOnlyLogFilter;


public class MainActivity extends SampleActivityBase {

    public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    // Whether the Log Fragment is currently shown
    private boolean mLogShown;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        AdapterTransitionFragment fragment = new AdapterTransitionFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem logToggle = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_toggle_log);
        logToggle.setVisible(findViewById(R.id.sample_output) instanceof ViewAnimator);
        logToggle.setTitle(mLogShown ? R.string.sample_hide_log : R.string.sample_show_log);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_toggle_log:
                mLogShown = !mLogShown;
                ViewAnimator output = (ViewAnimator) findViewById(R.id.sample_output);
                if (mLogShown) {
                    output.setDisplayedChild(1);
                } else {
                    output.setDisplayedChild(0);
                }
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /** Create a chain of targets that will receive log data */
    @Override
    public void initializeLogging() {
        // Wraps Android's native log framework.
        LogWrapper logWrapper = new LogWrapper();
        // Using Log, front-end to the logging chain, emulates android.util.log method signatures.
        Log.setLogNode(logWrapper);

        // Filter strips out everything except the message text.
        MessageOnlyLogFilter msgFilter = new MessageOnlyLogFilter();
        logWrapper.setNext(msgFilter);

        // On screen logging via a fragment with a TextView.
        LogFragment logFragment = (LogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.log_fragment);
        msgFilter.setNext(logFragment.getLogView());

        Log.i(TAG, "Ready");
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Show the manifest file and MainActivity code

Comment: Try to compile it again

Comment: Maybe you have a typo in your AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: I didn't modify anything you can download from here http://developer.android.com/samples/AdapterTransition/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had the issue of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.whatever" so I made a new package with the "com.example.whatever" and moved the java files to it and this fixed it for me. Hope it helps